# Get latest record from mongodb and process it with a callback

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am not sure how to modify the `db.collection.find().limit(1).sort({$natural:-1})`
 query that works in the console so that I can use it in my app. Currently I'm getting an `TypeError: Object #<Promise> has no method 'limit'` error so I'm guessing I have to add a callback with the result and process it there.

What I found on callbacks was this syntax, and I can't see how I can put my current limit(1) and sort() suffixes - I don't think they should be after the callback:

```
collection.find({'_id':o_id}, function(err, cursor){
  cursor.toArray(callback);
  db.close();
});
```

I'm doing it in nodejs, also I have monk available in my project.

USE CASE:

get the newest element, compare it's value to an element that I'm attempting to insert. If newest element in the db is older than the element I'm attempting to insert, insert it.

Comment: Not too sure about your "use case" from the information provided here. But perhaps take a look at ["tailable cursors"](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-tailable-cursor/) if you are trying to "event trap" the last insertion,

Comment: Try findOne() [MongoDB Docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOne/)

Comment: Have you tried chaining the sort first then limit after?

Comment: Deepak how would you use findone in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should work:

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/test', function(err, db) {
  var collection = db.collection('MyCollection');
  var cursor     = collection.find().limit(1).sort({ $natural : -1 });

  cursor.toArray(function(err, results) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log('%j', results);
    db.close();
  });
});
```

<s>However, I'm guessing that you might not be using the `mongodb` module, but perhaps Mongoose?</s>

Monk works differently from `mongodb` (which itself is modeled more like the MongoDB shell).

To perform something similar using Monk:

```
var db = require('monk')('localhost/test');

db.get('MyCollection').find({}, { sort : { $natural : -1 }, limit : 1 }).then(function(results) {
  console.log('%j', results);
  db.close();
}, function(err) {
  console.error(err);
  db.close();
});
```

Comment: Using mongodb and monk: `// Database
var mongo = require('mongodb');
var monk = require('monk');`

Comment: thanks Robert, one thing: why do you do `db.close()`? Won't that mean that I can't query the database again?

Comment: @LucasSeveryn these are standalone examples, in real world code where you'd use the same connection for multiple queries you wouldn't call `db.close()`.